# Passing the "identity function" as a block

Tags: ruby

Say I have Method, which expects a block. The block receives one argument, example:

```
f { |n| n*n } # square
```

If I want to invoke the function with a block which just returns the argument unchanged, it becomes

```
f { |n| n }  # identity
```

Is there a shortcut for such an "identity block"?

Background: The question arises from Rspec tests, where I stub methods using something like

```
allow(x).to receive(:f) { |n| .... }
```

In many cases, The block to be stubbed just receives the identity, i.e.

```
allow(x).to receive(:f) { |n| n }
```

and I wonder, whether there is a cleaner, more concise way to write this.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, [there is](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Object.html#method-i-itself). Try this

```
f(&:itself)
```

Comment: This is as good as it gets, but I don't know if I'd call it a "shortcut". Maybe "shorthand" would be more apt, as it mainly saves keystrokes.

Comment: Applied to the OP's RSpec example it's `allow(x).to receive(:f, &:itself)` – it might not be obvious, that a `&` block can be passed along other parameters.